# How to implement user authentication and sessions with Python

Tags: python, session, web-applications, authentication, bottle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bottle-friendly WSGI authentication library/middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533674/bottle-friendly-wsgi-authentication-library-middleware)

I'm creating a simple web application with Python and Bottle.
What would be some simple way to add user authentication / sessions to this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the topic [Bottle Friendly Wsgi Authentication Library Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533674/bottle-friendly-wsgi-authentication-library-middleware)