# Bottle.py HTTP Auth?

Tags: python, http, authentication, bottle, digest

How can I get my bottle.py app (Running in Paste or Cherrypy) to do HTTP (basic or digest) authentication? - I need to secure it, but cant find a any HOWTOs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement user authentication and sessions with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586141/how-to-implement-user-authentication-and-sessions-with-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bottle-friendly WSGI authentication library/middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533674/bottle-friendly-wsgi-authentication-library-middleware)

Answer (score 26):

bottle has a built in `auth_basic` decorator that can be used on a view:

```
from bottle import auth_basic, request, route

def check(user, pw):
    # Check user/pw here and return True/False

@route('/')
@auth_basic(check)
def home():
    return { 'data': request.auth }
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I am not sure how I can do check.

Comment: That's not a lot of information to go on, I'm afraid. Your `check` function depends entirely on what you want to do, so it could say e.g. `if user == "user" and pw == "hello": return True` – though in general of course I would not hard code a password like that!

Comment: What happens if you fail the check? Can you decide what is shown?

Comment: The auth_basic parameters are the function to call, the name of the auth realm, and the body to be displayed in the 401 error, so you can pass it in there.

Answer (score 2):

There are some libraries on GitHub like https://github.com/FedericoCeratto/bottle-cork that should help.  It may be easier to integrate than the repoze library suggested in the related post.