# Basic auth authentication in Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

How can i perform basic authentication in bottle framework? in flask i used to:

```
def check( username, password ):
    # This function is called to check if a username/password combination is valid
    return username == 'nikos' and password == '******'


def authenticate():
    # Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth
    return Response( 'Credentials of a registered user required!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="User!"'} )
```

and called as:

```
auth = request.authorization
if not auth or not counters.check( auth.username, auth.password ):
    return counters.authenticate()
```

How can i achieve the same in Bottle framework?

Comment: Just left an answer for you, with an example. Hope it helps! But it's worth noting that I found an answer after only 15 seconds of searching Google/Stackoverflow, so I recommend searching a bit more before posting a question. (Otherwise, your questions are likely to be marked as duplicates.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottle.py HTTP Auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272528/bottle-py-http-auth)

Comment: No, it is not. Before asking thsi question i have seen 3 threads here none of those helped me resolve my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23592568/593047), Bottle [natively contains](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#path_shift) a decorator that makes Basic Auth pretty straightforward:

```
from bottle import auth_basic, request, route

def is_authenticated_user(user, password):
    # You write this function. It must return
    # True if user/password is authenticated, or False to deny access.

@route('/')
@auth_basic(is_authenticated_user)
def home():
    return ['hooray, you are authenticated! your info is: {}'.format(request.auth)]
```

Comment: I did search and found some examples but it was very complicated to understand. Here in my case i have to save the 'username' user gives to authentication prompt to the database. Can i grab it as request.auth.username? And if the user gives in the prompt wrong credentials how can i send the user again to the authentication prompt?

Comment: Have you tried? The browser will reprompt upon wrong credentials, with the code I already gave you. Please try/experiment before you ask.

Comment: Yes ima trying it. Sorry iam new to Bottle. Can i decorator be within another decorator? is something like this correct? `@app.route( '/file', methods=['POST'] )
@auth_basic( is_authenticated_user )` I'am getting `Method not allowed.` if i place `@auth_basic( is_authenticated_user )` inside a view function i get syntax error? Where exactly should i place the auth decorator?

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work, i dont understnad why i'm getting method not allowed. Please help me.

Comment: Yes, decorators can be nested. Have you tried reversing the order of your decorators?

Comment: Hi Ron, i have managed to make auth_basic working, `Method not allowes' was due to another error i had not relevant to auth. I need to get the value that users gives in auth prompt thoough. I tried `request.auth.user` and `request.auth.username` but  that wont  return the value? How can i retrieve user data given in the auth prompt?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. If you want further help, I suggest closing this question and asking a new one

Comment: ook, i already asked, thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: Great, happy to help. Please accept this answer if you feel it answered your original question. Good luck!

Comment: Most certainly!

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from ron rothman with a basic auth solution using werkzeug.

```
from bottle import auth_basic, request, route
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


users = {'user1': generate_password_hash('pwd!')}


def is_authenticated_user(user, password):
    # You write this function. It must return
    # True if user/password is authenticated, or False to deny access.
    return user in users and check_password_hash(users[user], password)

@route('/')
@auth_basic(is_authenticated_user)
def home():
    return ['hooray, you are authenticated! your info is: {}'.format(request.auth)]
```